# Limit the width size in <pre>

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a pre to limit the width size that does not exceed the table, try using this tag:

```
<?php
echo "<pre style='max-width:1px;'>".$long_string."</pre>";
?>
```

both the `<pre>` and the table but does not work in any case.

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 36):

Setting `max-width` on a `pre` element actually restricts it width. You can see this by inspecting the element using a browser’s Developer Tools and also simply by setting a background color on it, say `pre { background: yellow }`. Note: testing this with the `outline` property gives a wrong result in Firefox; but even it implements the `border` property correctly.

As usual in rendering elements, content may overflow the width of the element, and the default is visible overflow. If you wish to cut it off, rendering just the part that fits in, set `pre { overflow: hidden }`. If you wish to indicate truncation with an ellipsis “…”, set also `pre { text-overflow: ellipsis; }`.

If you would want to make long lines wrap when needed to make the content fit, you can instead set `pre { white-space: pre-wrap }`. However, long strings without spaces could still cause overflow. This can be prevented by adding `pre { word-wrap: break-word; }` (old syntax) or `pre { overflow-wrap: break-word; }` (new syntax, with slightly more limited browser support).

Comment: Also this helped. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

Answer (score 1):

Max-width with vertical scrolling:

```html
<pre style="overflow-y:scroll; max-width:400px; height:80px; border:0.5px solid lightgray; padding:5px; white-space:pre-wrap;">
These license terms are an agreement between you and Microsoft Corporation (or based on where you live, one of its affiliates). They apply to the software named above. The terms also apply to any Microsoft services or updates for the software, except to the extent those have different terms.
</pre>
```